# Relational algebra for joining multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I am looking for the relational algebra for this operation: "Select the make_name and model_name of all cars with the color_name white"

Here I am attaching the schema of my tables
[this is the schema of tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXFYb.png)

Comment: What have you done already?

Comment: i have written a sql query but i am not sure about its accuracy.

Comment: so if you could explain the relational algebra for this problem then that will be appreciated. thank you.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

Answer (score 0):

> *I am looking for the relational algebra for this operation: "Select the make_name and model_name of all cars with the color_name white"*

(I am not sure if you want the actual RA or the SQL.)

The answer is, you can't.  Because the stated requirement, the three relations have nothing that relates them.  You can join them and obtain a Cartesian Product, but that is all the possibilities, not the actuals.

So you need to find something that relates the three relations.  Which is Inventory.  So the question (stated in SQL pseudo-code) becomes:

- Select the make_name and model_name of cars in the inventory with the color_name white

That is easy, but the RA/SQL is cumbersome because the tables are a mess.

By the way, that schema is horrible.  It is a filing system, nothing Relational about it.  It has no Relational Integrity, or power, or speed.  If you request it, I can provide a Relational Data Model to fill the requirement, which will have full Relational Integrity, power, and speed.  Then both the RA and the SQL will be straight-forward.

- Are you sure that a Vehicle (Make, Model, Year), and not an Inventory item, is incentivised ?